# FLUTTER : How to only rebuild the top page in stack flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, setstate, flutter-navigation

I have an issue with rebuilding pages in the stack with Flutter

[image: This is all my users and have added the search to the top appBar]

This is all my users and have added the search to the top appBar.
But it works with conditions to see if it is widgets there then get height of the widgets that is being fixed underneath the appBar...But that happens asynchronously.

So when firstLoad it works but when I call setState it then rebuilds all the pages in the stack and with that it looks like this

[image]

This is how it looks after a set state. The problem i saw is that the previous pages have an influence. I couldn't find a good viable solution to this. Will explain my architecture.

I have a page Layout that is a container wrapper for all my pages that has it's appBar styles and just sends through the children. But that is the page Layout wrapper that is being rebuild every time the a set States happen

HOW I GET MY WIDGET SIZE

[image]

HOW I IMPLEMENTED IT

[image]

It goes in the else with the other pages in the stack.. I tried putting it in the initState but it never goes inside because it is used in the other pages in the stack

I only need an implementation to rebuild the TOP page in the stack.

PAGE LAYOUT

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/controllers/channel_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/controllers/user_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/main.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/models/channels_model.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/utils/functions.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/views/channels/func.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/views/home/home.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/views/menu/permissions/choose_assign_group.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/builders/KNetworkFadeImage.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/builders/kPopups.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/drawerDara.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? topTabs;
  final TabController? topTabController;
  final List<Widget>? children;
  final List<Widget>? childrenFixed;
  final Function? leftActionFunction;
  final Icon? leftActionIcon;
  final Drawer? drawer;
  final Function? logOutPressed;
  final bool showOptionsMenu;
  final Widget? optionMenu;
  final Widget? bottomNavigationBar;
  final String? backGroundImage;
  final ScrollController? scrollController;

  CustomAppBar({
    required this.title,
    this.topTabs,
    this.topTabController,
    this.leftActionFunction,
    this.leftActionIcon,
    this.children,
    this.childrenFixed,
    this.drawer,
    this.logOutPressed,
    this.showOptionsMenu = false,
    this.optionMenu,
    this.bottomNavigationBar,
    this.backGroundImage,
    this.scrollController,
  });

  @override
  _CustomAppBarState createState() => _CustomAppBarState();
}

double app_content_height = 0;
double fixedWidgetSize = 0;
String prevTitle = "";

class _CustomAppBarState extends State<CustomAppBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  _toggleAnimation() {
    scaffoldkey.currentState!.openDrawer();
  }

  double _getAppBarSize() {
    double fixedHeightInclude = fixedWidgetSize;

    if (widget.topTabs != null) {
      fixedHeightInclude += 100;
    } else if (widget.title == "") {
      fixedHeightInclude += 0;
    } else {
      fixedHeightInclude += 60;
    }
    return fixedHeightInclude;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // if (widget.title != global_title) return SizedBox();

    List<Widget> arr = [];
    Widget arrView = SizedBox();
    double statusBar = 0;

    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    Widget? fixedChild = SizedBox();

    if ((widget.childrenFixed?.length ?? 0) > 1) {
      fixedChild = WidgetSize(
        child: Column(children: widget.childrenFixed!),
        onChange: (Size size) {
          fixedWidgetSize = 0;
          setState(() {
            fixedWidgetSize = size.height;
          });
          kPrint("fixedWidgetSize ${size.height}");
        },
      );
    } else {
      fixedWidgetSize = 0;
    }

    // Widget? fixedChild = (widget.childrenFixed?.length ?? 0) > 1
    //     ? WidgetSize(
    //         child: Column(children: widget.childrenFixed!),
    //         onChange: (Size size) {
    //           fixedWidgetSize = 0;
    //           setState(() {
    //             fixedWidgetSize = size.height;
    //           });
    //           kPrint("fixedWidgetSize ${size.height}");
    //         },
    //       )
    //     : SizedBox();

    app_content_height =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - _getAppBarSize() - statusBar;

    if (widget.title != "") {
      arr.add(
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: widget.showOptionsMenu == true
                  ? IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () => _toggleAnimation(),
                    )
                  : IconButton(
                      icon: widget.leftActionIcon ??
                          const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (widget.leftActionFunction != null) {
                          widget.leftActionFunction!();
                        } else {
                          if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                            Get.back();
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: SizedBox()),
            Expanded(
              flex: 10,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: widget.logOutPressed != null
                  ? IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.power_settings_new_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        widget.logOutPressed!();
                      },
                    )
                  : widget.optionMenu ?? Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    if (widget.topTabs != null) {
      List<Widget> tempTopBar = [];
      List<Widget> tempTopView = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < widget.topTabs!.length; i++) {
        String key = widget.topTabs![i].keys
            .toString()
            .replaceAll("(", "")
            .replaceAll(")", "");

        Widget value = widget.topTabs![i][key];
        tempTopBar.add(Tab(text: key));
        tempTopView.add(SingleChildScrollView(child: value));
      }

      arr.add(
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 30,
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: widget.topTabs!.length,
                child: TabBar(
                  labelPadding: widget.topTabs!.length == 2
                      ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0)
                      : const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  controller: widget.topTabController,
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                  indicator: CircleTabIndicator(color: Colors.white, radius: 4),
                  isScrollable: true,
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  tabs: tempTopBar,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

      // arr.add(child);
      arrView = Container(
        width: _width,
        height: app_content_height,
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: widget.topTabController,
          children: tempTopView,
        ),
      );
    }

    if (widget.children != null) {
      arrView = Container(
        width: _width,
        height: app_content_height,
        child: ListView(
          // controller: widget.scrollController ?? ScrollController(),
          children: widget.children!,
        ),
      );
    }

    _getStatus() {
      if (statusBar > 0) {
        Color color = AppColors.kBlue;

        return Container(
          height: Get.height * 0.03,
          width: Get.width,
          color: color,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              "",
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return const SizedBox();
      }
    }

    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
                  true, //That the keyboard shows correctly
              extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
              key: scaffoldkey,
              appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(
                    _getAppBarSize()), // here the desired height
                child: Container(
                  decoration: kAppBarBoxDecorations,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: arr,
                      ),
                      fixedChild,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountName: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Channels element =
                              ChannelController.to.gSelectedChannel.value;
                          getChannelRoles(element);
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "${ChannelController.to.gSelectedChannel.value.rolDesc} >",
                        ),
                      ),
                      accountEmail: Text(
                          UserController.to.gUserModel.value.email.toString()),
                      currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                          child: const CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"),
                          ),
                          onTap: () => print("Current User")),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                "${URLS.keyBaseUrl}/assets/images/background/background7.jpg")),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text("Home"),
                      trailing: const Icon(Icons.home),
                      onTap: () =>
                          Get.toNamed(Home.router, preventDuplicates: false),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text("Menu Permissions"),
                      trailing: const Icon(Icons.home),
                      onTap: () => Get.toNamed(ChooseAssignGroup.router,
                          preventDuplicates: false),
                    ),
                    const Divider(
                      thickness: 1.0,
                    ),
                    drawerData(),
                    const Divider(
                      thickness: 1.0,
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text("Close"),
                      trailing: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text("Log Out"),
                      trailing: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                      onTap: () => UserController.to.logOutUser(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: Container(
                decoration: widget.backGroundImage != null
                    ? BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
                          image: NetworkImage(widget.backGroundImage!),
                        ),
                      )
                    : BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: _getAppBarSize()),
                    child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                      context: context,
                      removeTop: true,
                      child: arrView,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: widget.bottomNavigationBar,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  final BoxPainter _painter;

  CircleTabIndicator({required Color color, required double radius})
      : _painter = _CirclePainter(color, radius);

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged()?]) => _painter;
}

class _CirclePainter extends BoxPainter {
  final Paint _paint;
  final double radius;

  _CirclePainter(Color color, this.radius)
      : _paint = Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..isAntiAlias = true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Offset circleOffset =
        offset + Offset(cfg.size!.width / 2, cfg.size!.height - radius);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleOffset, radius, _paint);
  }
}

class WidgetSize extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function onChange;

  const WidgetSize({
    required this.onChange,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  _WidgetSizeState createState() => _WidgetSizeState();
}

class _WidgetSizeState extends State<WidgetSize> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(postFrameCallback);
    return Container(
      key: widgetKey,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  var widgetKey = GlobalKey();
  var oldSize;

  void postFrameCallback(_) {
    var context = widgetKey.currentContext;
    if (context == null) return;

    var newSize = context.size;
    if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    oldSize = newSize;
    widget.onChange(newSize);
  }
}
```

ALL VERIFIED USERS

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/controllers/channel_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/controllers/user_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/main.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/thirdParty/googleSignin.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/utils/functions.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/views/menu/permissions/menu_assign.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/builders/kPopups.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/buttons/KIconOnlyButton.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/builders/KNetworkFadeImage.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/builders/customAppBar.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/buttons/KButton.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/cards/KStudentInfoCard.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/cards/kStudentCard.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/input/KInputBar.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/input/KTextField.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/static/kLabel.dart';
import 'package:flutterweb/widgets/text/kInfo.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart';

class AllVerifiedUsers extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String router = "/allVerifiedUsers";

  AllVerifiedUsers({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

// The controller for the ListView
late ScrollController _controller;

class _MyPageState extends State<AllVerifiedUsers> {
// The controller for the ListView
  late ScrollController _controllerTest;
  int _page = 1;
  final int _limit = 20;
  bool _hasNextPage = true;
  bool _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
  bool _isLoadMoreRunning = false;
  List<UserModel> _posts = [];
  String searchVal = "";

  void _firstLoad() async {
    setState(() {
      _isFirstLoadRunning = true;
    });
    try {
      List<UserModel> lUserMode = await ChannelController.to
          .fetchUsersChannels(_limit, _page, searchVal);
      setState(() {
        _posts = lUserMode;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      kPrint('Something went wrong');
    }

    setState(() {
      _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
    });
  }

  void _loadMore() async {
    if (_isFirstLoadRunning == false &&
        _isLoadMoreRunning == false &&
        _controller.position.extentAfter < 300) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = true; // Display a progress indicator at the bottom
      });
      _page += 1; // Increase _page by 1
      try {
        List<UserModel> lUserMode = await ChannelController.to
            .fetchUsersChannels(_limit, _page, searchVal);

        if (lUserMode.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            _hasNextPage = true;
            _posts.addAll(lUserMode);
          });
        } else {
          // This means there is no more data
          // and therefore, we will not send another GET request
          setState(() {
            _hasNextPage = false;
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        print('Something went wrong!');
      }

      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firstLoad();
    _controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_loadMore);
    _controllerTest = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() => {kPrint("CustomView Scroll")});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.removeListener(_loadMore);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    global_title = "All Verified Users";
    return CustomAppBar(
      title: "All Verified Users",
      scrollController: _controllerTest,
      childrenFixed: [
        kAddSpace(2),
        CustomInputBar(
          inverse: true,
          title: "Search",
          onChanged: (String value) {
            if (value == "") {
              _firstLoad();
              return;
            }

            setState(() {
              searchVal = value;
              _posts = [];
            });
            _loadMore();
          },
        ),
      ],
      children: [
        kAddSpace(2),
        KLabel(
          label: "Choose Verified User",
        ),
        kAddSpace(2),
        _isFirstLoadRunning
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: app_content_height,
                    // width: Get.width,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      controller: _controller,
                      itemCount: _posts.length,
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        UserModel item = _posts[index];

                        return KStudentCard(
                          imgUrl: "",
                          onPressed: () {
                            ChannelController.to.gSelectedMenuUserModel.value =
                                item;

                            Get.toNamed(MenuAssign.router);
                          },
                          name: "${item.name} ${item.surname}",
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

                  // when the _loadMore function is running
                  if (_isLoadMoreRunning == true)
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 40),
                      child: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    ),

                  // When nothing else to load
                  if (_hasNextPage == false)
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 40),
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text('You have fetched all of the content'),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
        kAddSpace(2),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you please share code instead of screenshots? That would make helping you way easier.  Also, I am a little unsure why you use the the `height`. Does showing the children (users) in a `ListView` not work? And then updating that `ListView` based on the user input?

Comment: No probs, have added the code. Thank you

Comment: The reason why is i want it to be fixed and the rest of the page scrollable

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the idea is a fixed `TextArea` and a scrollable `List` beneath. A solution that works without computing any `height` would be:

```dart
final items = List<String>.generate(1000, (i) => 'Item $i');

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(children: [
      //
      // TEXTBOX
      //
      Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: TextFormField(
                  // controller: controller,
                  ))),
      const SizedBox(height: 16),
      //
      // LIST
      //
      Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true, // IMPORTANT
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(items[index]);
              })),
    ]),
  );
}
```

Comment: Not exactly... The childrenFixed property is dynamic... That's why I want to get the height of the widgets.... The problem lies in pages in the stack rebuilding the CustomAppBar component

Comment: The main question is to only rebuild top stack navigation in flutter

Comment: But fixed it with adding static height